Fantasy book series about an orphaned girl who works as a concert employee and steals a genie lamp from a fae band
I read this on the Nook around 5 or 6 years ago. I think it is a YA fantasy novel and part of series.
It was about a girl who was orphaned. As she grows up, she works in the human world that is controlled by all paranormal-like creatures, as some sort of concert employee. The band that is playing is fae and one of them happens to be a prince. She sneaks into the band's van and steals the genie lamp(?). She gets caught, either at the start or later on, but doesn't realize it, as the band makes her think she is a groupie? Anyways, she is mixed with fairy blood or a rare type of succubus demon, something really powerful, and there is a group of people that want to kill her.
